# Operators in C# Generics

Tags: c#, generics

In C++ we can write following:

```
template <typename T>

    void Print(T a, T b) 
      {
          cout<<a+b<<endl;
      }

Print(12,56) or Print('c','s');
```

If we overload operators for user-define types(classes) we can also write:

```
Person a, b; Print(a,b);
```

but in C# we cant write operators such as + - or * / 
why we can't write this?
and how we can do it(use operators in Generic Methods)?

Comment: C# does not support this, because C# generics are directly part of the type system. (see constraints)

Comment: `" in C# we cant write operators such as + - or * /"` we can't? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @JacobKrall not if you're a generic class. You can't specify the constraints of the generic arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how we can do it(use operators in Generic Methods)

**Generally, we can't.** For most operators, if used with a type parameter (say `T`), the compiler cannot work out an applicable overload to use at compile-time.

If you write user-defined operators on a **base class** (that is on a reference type that is non-sealed), you can use them if you have a constraint. For example `System.Uri` is a non-sealed class that overloads the `==` operator. Then if you do:

```
class Test<T> where T : Uri
{
  internal void Method(T x, T y)
  {
    bool ok = x == y;
  }
}
```

the user-defined overload is used. Same with other operators, of course.

But generally you want to do this with pre-defined **value types** and pre-defined operators, for example `T` is some numeric type (`struct`), and you want `==` (equality) or `*` (multiplication) or `<<` (bit shift on integer) or similar. But that is not possible in C#.

It is possible to use `dynamic` instead of generic types, but obviously that is entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found thus far is in the [MiscUtils](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) library.  It uses expression trees to perform the operations at runtime. It's quite good and the performance is pretty good as well.

Instead of using, say, `operator+`, you call `Operator.Add`.  If the two types expose an `operator+` that allows for the operation then the call will succeed. And work as expected.

It's an unfortunate limitation of the C# generics implementation (and the CLR as well).  Something more akin to C++ templates would be very useful at times.

Comment: Well the good news is of course that C# generics are not resolved at compile time, unlike C++ templates.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde: Well, the types are certainly resolved at compile time, which is why the OP is having this problem to begin with.  There are advantages to both systems, but I tend to prefer templates. They're more powerful.  Using generics in the general case is often delightful, but sometimes it is painful.  I wrote an image processing library in C# and would have killed for the ability to perform mathematical operations on pixels from different image types in one function without adding a bunch of overhead.

Comment: The instantiations are resolved at compile time, but the generic itself is compiled into an assembly. With C++ templates, you include the entire template, code and all, and it's compiled at the instantiation. That's a big difference. Yes, C++ templates are more powerful (I remember operator() overloading on a class to pass it as a function very fondly) but there's issues. Generics are a different beast, with a smaller but clearer scope.

Answer (score 0):

> why we can't write this?

Because this is what the langauge specification says.

> and how can do it(use operators in Generic Methods)?

We can not.

Limitation of C#.

On the underlying reasons - hard to guess and off topic here (speculation based), but operators are not supported. Period.

Comment: There is a very simple reason why: There is no way to specify a type that has an operator.  (and the CLR doesn't support virtual static calls)

Comment: Sorry, no real reasons - this could both be changed by the powers to be.